# Typescript: how to make a function return a type

Tags: typescript

How to make a function return an argument as is?

This is what I tried:

```
function init<T>(t: T): T {
  // init
  return t
}

class W {
  constructor(public a: string) {}
}

let InitedW = init(W)
let w: InitedW // err: Exported variable 'w' has or is using private name 'InitedW'
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDMMoB4AqA+AFFALkUwEojNEBvAKEUQHp7lUpbEAnAUyhHaVYC+1ahAA2AQwDOkxAHUqbCAklR2IaHHa4ADiABGomBETiiK9igDmJKkKHVR3RAEkWnACbyAvMzS5ZJA5OAO5Ermge8oyInOzs1EA)

but here, the returned type InitedW is only a value and cant be used as a type. Even though it is `typoef W`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you are trying to reference a value as a type. In TypeScript you can not reference a type as a value and vice versa, you can not reference a value as a type.

You wrote the code:

```
let InitedW = init(W);
```

What this code means is that you are assigning a **return value** of init() to a **value** with a name `InitedW`.

While on the next line you are trying to reference it as it was a type:

```
let w: InitedW; // InitedW is a value, not a type, error
```

One of the *possible solutions* is to pass `W` in type annotation to the variable. That means, that your variable expect to get instance of the `W`. Inferring takes place here and `init` return type will be `W`, so that your generic `T` in `init` becomes `W`.

However, there is one small change must be done as well. You need to explain that `init` argument is not just `W`, but something that will create an instance of `W`.

```
function init<T>(t: new(...args: unknown[]) => T): T {
  // 1. T -> W because you expect to get W there
  // 2. t: new() => T becomes t: new() => W
  // 
  // you can init here your constructor, e.g. and return it

  return new t();
}

let w: W = init(W);
```

[Link to the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDMMoB4AqA%20AFNAJwC5EwBTAd1wDpaBDAgcwGcS6wBPAbQF0BKRAF5siTHxKZEAbwBQiRATJQQBJOQqJCuPgG4ZAXxkyIAGzrNmiAOrS5mhMygEQ0OAVwAHEACMTMCIh0JI4EKIwCUoaGMiZKiBQkNoLIqFC4VnwyQA)

---

**UPD:** after discussion in comments, turns out the author wants to make some kind of registry for classes:

```
class A { }
class B { }
class C { }

const someSortOfRegistryOfYours: Map<string, any> = new Map();
function init<T>(name: string, ctr: T): T {
  someSortOfRegistryOfYours.set(name, ctr);
  return ctr;
}

const AA = init("A", A);
const BB = init("B", B);
const CC = init("C", C);

const instanceOfA = new AA();
const instanceOfB = new BB();
const instanceOfC = new CC();
```

[Link to playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G9oF8BQpIwEKJe8U0AwrmugPYB2EALtBOQLYCmAyuQE40DyAZgErMA5gEtaHAJ58AmuQCuHCAC5oAWTAAHADziRlIQBpoYShIB80ALzRKzAO5rNACgCUAblS85lYDRFVoPREaLQAVMydKMBYVXX0jXw4VUJdkxFRoeiY2Th4BYTEaSRl5RQA6CGYaSOjmBKL3DOgOKoVKaESPMmAqWjh4ayDqgCJYYaNYRp7qOiwcQcpgp2GscegsKd66IhIFpeGiNaJGihnAmZNgZj4Bm3t+1w9pvr1aS+veebuHOcfTl4uPg+u2+xCIfyAA)

Comment: There's one thing I'd like to highlight. In TS declaring `class W { ... }` will create both a runtime value `W` (the constructor function), and a design time type of the **same name** `W` (the interface for the instance of class `W`), thus making `let w: W` valid, cus here we're referring to `W` as the type not the value.

Comment: However, `init(W)` returns the constructor function `W` itself (not its instance), the type of which should be `typeof W` not `W`, thus `let w: W = init(W)` will raise error `typeof W` is not assignable to `W`

Comment: Pay attention to OP code. There is a commented section `// init`, so I assume that `t` in `init` refers to already instantiated instance, not the constructor.

Comment: @EugeneObrezkov Sorry for the late answere. I was actually not intending to instanciate `W` in `init` just add it to a registry. While your anwser works fine for the code in my question, I was actually trying to achive a export like so: `export default init(class W{...})`. Sorry for being inprecise. For that I would really need `init` to return the value of W **and** the type. Do you think this is somehow possible?

Comment: [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=8&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDMMoB4AqA+AFNAJwC5EwBTAd1wDpaBDAgcwGcS6wBPAbQF0BKRAF5siTHxKZEAbwBQiRATJQQBJOQqJCuPgG4ZAXxkyyADwAOcAlEQATMsDogANtZRp8Tus2aIA6tLlNBGYoAhBoS1wzEAAjJxgIRDoSEIIURgEpQ30+GSA)

Comment: If I understood your statement about registry correctly, so this is what you are trying to do, right? - [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G9oF8BQpIwEKJe8U0AwrmugPYB2EALtBOQLYCmAyuQE40DyAZgErMA5gEtaHAJ58AmuQCuHCAC5oAWTAAHADziRlIQBpoYShIB80ALzRKzAO5rNACgCUAblS85lYDRFVoPREaLQAVMydKMBYVXX0jXw4VUJdkxFRoeiY2Th4BYTEaSRl5RQA6CGYaSOjmBKL3DOgOKoVKaESPMmAqWjh4ayDqgCJYYaNYRp7qOiwcQcpgp2GscegsKd66IhIFpeGiNaJGihnAmZNgZj4Bm3t+1w9pvr1aS+veebuHOcfTl4uPg+u2+xCIfyAA)

Comment: @EugeneObrezkov Yes, just the types are [missing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=11&ssc=24&pln=11&pc=35#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G9oF8BQpIwEKJe8U0AwrmugPYB2EALtBOQLYCmAyuQE40DyAZgErMA5gEtaHAJ58AmuQCuHCAC5oAWTAAHADziRlIQBpoYShIB80ALzRKzAO5rNACgCUAblS85lYDRFVoPREaLQAVMydKMBYVXX0jXw4VUJdkxFRoeiY2Th4BYTEaSRl5RQA6CGYaSOjmBKL3DOgOKoVKaESPMmAqWjh4ayDqgCJYYaNYRp7qOiwcQcpgp2GscegsKd66IhIFpeGiNaJGihnAmZNgZj5YFVgBm3t+1w9pvr1aS+veLBU5q0eDjmL1O7wuPm+RBUOwBtgcOxBQA) here

Comment: Let me repeat what I've already told, you can not use value as a type! The "types" that is missing for you is not types at all - they are values - you can not use them as a type.